# Add command line arguments to Azure WebJob deployment

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm deploying webjob to Azure using VS2015, but cannot find way to add command line in webjob-publish-settings.json.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Is the WebJobs continuous or triggered? Also, do you want to pass a constant command line, or one that varies?

Comment: It is continuous. I want to pass constant command line like /doSomething

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

- Add a `run.cmd` file to your WebJob in VS (same place as your `Program.cs`)
- Make sure to set this file's Copy to Output Directory to `Copy if newer` (in the file properties)
- In that file, just add one line that has: `NameOfYourExe.exe /dosomething`

When deployed to Azure (under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\MyContinuousWebJob`), this file will take precedence of the `.exe`, and will end up running the `.exe` with your params.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Arguments are not part of the definition of the json:

[webjob-publish-settings.json definition](http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json#sthash.oOndIylp.dpuf)

So adding them is not possible in the current version.