# Azure webjob argument

Tags: c#, azure, cron, command-line-arguments, azure-webjobs

I am publishing my console application as an Azure WebJob. I would like to run the webjob every day at 0.30 am. But just for testing, I am trying currently with every 5 minutes. Which works fine. But I also want to use an argument, which is passing to the arg[0] to my `static void Main(string[] args)` method.

My Web Deploy.pubxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>False</ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://testProjectHello.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>testProjectHello.scm.azurewebsites.net:443</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>testProjectHello</DeployIisAppPath>
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <UserName>$testProjectHello</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <_DestinationType>AzureWebSite</_DestinationType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

webjob-publish-settings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "webjobNameTest",
  "runMode": "OnDemand"
}
```

My settings.job file:

```
{
  "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
}
```

In the azure portal I see the following:

> NAME TYPE STATUS SCHEDULE
>
> webJobNameTest Triggered Ready 0 */5 * * * *

How can I pass an argument in my web job? Is it also possible to deploy multiple azure web jobs with different parameters from one console application? So I can run the webjob every day, and every week and every month. Including a parameter so my logic knows whether to get the day, week or month data.

Comment: Have you looked at this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362847/add-command-line-arguments-to-azure-webjob-deployment

Comment: In that way, it looks like I have to create a console app and deploy it for each variable. I've also seen that it's possible to get the webjob name via the WEBJOBS_NAME environment variable. In that way I don't need to create a new console app, but I will have to change the logic. I hope there's a way to just deploy 3 web jobs with 3 different parameters with just one single click.

Comment: Yup, I see what you are saying.  Maybe try this suggestion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735831/can-multiple-azure-webjobs-share-the-same-assemblies

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer because I do not qualify for comments. This is what worked for me.

**Step 1 - Create a new subfolder under %HOME%* folder where your custom console exe will reside**

- Browse to Azure portal.
- Create a new **Web App** under **Service App**
- From the Tools menu under your **Service App**, launch *Kudu* web site
- On the Kudu web site, click on *Debug Console* --> *CMD*

e.g. In my case, I created a subfolder **Tool** under **d:\Home** and uploaded **MyConsole.exe** and accompanying files like DLLs and MyConsole.exe.config to **d:\Home\Tool**

**Step 2 - Create a BAT file to launch your custom console EXE**

I created a .BAT file on my local disk, say **Launcher.bat**. This BAT file has only 1 line

```
d:\Home\Tool\MyConsole.exe arg1  arg2
```

**Step 3 - Create a scheduled Web job using the BAT file**

- Browse to Azure portal.
- Select your *Web app* from *App Services*
- Select *Web job*

Create a scheduled web job. Upload the file **Launcher.BAT** file that you created in your earlier step. Configure schedule and create the job.

**Caveats**

1. You will need to create a new .BAT file for every instance of command line argument
2. However you do not need to duplicate the binaries

Hope this helps.